# Does Chrome's V8 engine use x86-64 instruction set

Tags: google-chrome, x86-64, v8

I was wondering, is Google Chrome's V8 engine translating JavaScript to use x86-64 specific instructions, such as the 64-bit SIMD instructions? (Even through the process is running in 32-bit mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIMD instructions aren't exclusive to x86-64, x86-64 just includes SSE & SSE2 as a standard.

if you look at the v8 source, you'll notice they have an JIT assembler specifically for x64. you could also gleam from the source what SIMD instructions are used.